# Stop form from submitting without javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

The problem is quite simple to understand but quite hard to execute. I am currently facing some clients that turn off their browser Javascript by default and this screw up my website a bit. Since my website send ajax requests on form submit, stop the form submit using Javascript, turning JS off means the form will be sent through and that's unexpectedly.

What I am trying to ask and achieve is whether it is possible to just using html purely to stop a form from submitting?

Comment: Default type attribute for a button is "submit" you can change this by: ```<button type="button">Submit</button>``` I think this will stop form from submitting

Comment: But what do you want the form to do if it doesn't submit and there's no JS logic to govern it?

ie I the user enter details to the form. I hit submit. What is expected to happen?

Comment: Turning off JS nowadays is way 1990 anyway, so I would just kick them with a simple `<noscript>` tag ...

Comment: @stwilz [...] and *profit*?

Comment: @tevemadar :thumbsup:

Comment: @stwilz since without JS, the form is submitted through a POST request, which my server is not expected to get. I think what I want is it just not doing anything.

Comment: @tevemadar to stop showing the error exception page :-?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer is; to have the original form action point to an error page, asking the user to turn on javascript. 
Then let your javascript code fill in the form action parameter, once the ajax state is complete.

Alternatively or additionally, you could use a `<noscript>` tag as suggested in the comments, to generate a message on the original page.

Comment: I will use `<noscript>` tag to show an error on top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply change your submit button tag to an input and style it to look like a button and remove the type="submit" that's all. with out ajax it will not respond.